# Error CS0117: "Marshal" does not contain a definition for "GetTypeFromCLSID"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I've made a project in .NET and get constant error in Visual Studio 2017 like in the title above.

I was looking for different solutions but nothing worked so I've decided to ask my question here so maybe you will be able to help me.

Code:

```
 namespace MSBuilderTx
{
    using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security.AccessControl;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Timers;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    internal class Program
    {
        private const int MAXTITLE = 0xff;
        private static ArrayList mTitlesList;
        private static Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="EnumDesktopWindows", 
        CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern bool _EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr 
        hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetWindowText", 
        CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern int _GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, 
        StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);
        public static void CreateShortcut(string shortcutName, string 
        shortcutPath, string targetFileLocation)
        {
            string pathLink = Path.Combine(shortcutPath, shortcutName 
            + ".lnk");
            WshShell shell = (WshShell) 
            Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new 
            Guid("72C24DD5-D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8")));
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut) 
            shell.CreateShortcut(pathLink);
            shortcut.Description = "Pixie Shortcut";
            shortcut.TargetPath = targetFileLocation;
            shortcut.Save();
        }
```

Line

```
WshShell shell = (WshShell) 
Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("72C24DD5- 
D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8")));
```

gives an error message.

Comment: It is Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(), not Marshal.

Comment: @HansPassant: There's a method in Marshal as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gettypefromclsid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please tell us which version of the framework you're targeting.

Comment: (That line of code works for me in a minimal example, btw.)

Comment: Hi,I'm targeting version 4.0.

Comment: Right, use Type.GetTypeFromCLSID() instead.  The Marshal method did not become available until version 4.5.  This kind of duplication is not pretty but was necessary in 4.5 due to added support for WinRT apps.  They can't support the Type class well, substituted with TypeInfo.

Comment: Thank you very much,it worked!